# How do you make an Image land on platforms?

Tags: javascript, css, html

**My Question is, How do you make an image land on the red platforms shown?** I have my code below of how I set it up so far. I really have know idea how Nintendo made Mario lol it's crazy. **Looks easier than it looks or is it just me?**

[image: Game Play Picture]

My CSS File

```
body {
        background-color: #000;
        color: #FF0;        
}

#BG {
        position: absolute;
        top: 10px;
        left: 10px;        
}        
#MmEnu {
        position: absolute;
        top: 10px;
        left: 10px;        
}
#mainDis {
        position: absolute;
        top: 13px;
        left: 15px;                
}

#land01 {
        position: absolute;
        top: 250px;
        left: 350px;
}

#land00 {
        position: absolute;
        top: 120px;
        left: 250px;
}
```

My Index File

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<title>GENERATION CUBE-X</title>
<head>

<link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "css/gencubex.css" />

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<script src = "class/loadImages.js"></script>
<script src = "class/myvis.js"></script>
<script src = "class/mainMenu.js"></script>
<script src = "class/display.js"></script>
<script src = "class/theGame.js"></script>
<script src = "class/landThis.js"></script>

</head>
<body onLoad = "MAINM(), myvisible()">    

<div id = "BG"> 
<img src = "images/bg.png" width = "1023" height = "395" />
</div>
<div id = "MmEnu">
<img src = "images/mainMenu.png" width = "1023" height = "395" />
</div>
<div id = "mainDis">
<img src = "images/display.png" width = "900" height = "60" />
</div>

<div id = "land00">

</div>
<div id = "land01">

</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Move Platform .js

```
var cTAdd = 0;
var setThis = 1;
function landT() {
        setThis = setTimeout(landT, 500);

        cTAdd = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100 + 1);

        var block00 = document.createElement("img");

        if (cTAdd > 0 && cTAdd < 25) {
                block00.src = "images/sep2.png";
        }
        if (cTAdd > 25 && cTAdd < 50) {
                block00.src = "images/sep1.png";
        }
        if (cTAdd > 50 && cTAdd < 100) {
                block00.src = "images/platform00.png";
        }

        document.getElementById("land01").appendChild(block00);

        var block01 = document.createElement("img");

        if (cTAdd > 0 && cTAdd < 25) {
                block01.src = "images/platform00.png";
        }
        if (cTAdd > 25 && cTAdd < 50) {
                block01.src = "images/sep2.png";
        }
        if (cTAdd > 50 && cTAdd < 100) {
                block01.src = "images/sep1.png";
        }

        document.getElementById("land00").appendChild(block01);


}

var thisSet = 1;
function moveLand() {

        thisSet = setTimeout(moveLand, 40);
        moveBlock1 = moveBlock1 - 10;
        document.getElementById("land00").style.left = moveBlock1 + "px";
        document.getElementById("land01").style.left = moveBlock1 + "px";                
}
```

Main .js

```
var getPlatF1POSX = 0;
var getPlatF1POSY = 0;
var addVar = 0;
var addVar2 = 0;
var addVar3 = 0;
function loadGame() {
        document.getElementsByTagName("DIV")[4].style.visibility = "visible";
        addEventListener('mousemove', getData, false);
        addEventListener('keydown', movePlayer, false);
        addEventListener('keyup', stopPlayer, false);
        movePlat();
}

function getData(gData) {

}

var thisThis = 1;
var moveBlock1 = 350;
var stLandT = 0;
function movePlat() {

}

function movePlayer(mPlayer) {
        switch (mPlayer.keyCode) {
                case 39:
                        if (stLandT == 0) {
                                setThis = setTimeout(landT, 500);
                                thisSet = setTimeout(moveLand, 40);
                                stLandT = 1;
                        }
                break;

                case 38:

                break;
        }
}

function stopPlayer(sPlayer) {
        switch (sPlayer.keyCode) {
                case 39:
                        clearTimeout(setThis);
                        clearTimeout(thisSet);
                        stLandT = 0;
                break;
        }
}
```

Comment: position your element absolute (like you did) and use on `element.getBoundingClientRect()` to get the positioning of the elements (red platforms) and then just put your image 1px above the red platform.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you I will give it a try. :) This has taken me forever lol

Comment: @SNLippold, Nintendo didn't make Mario using HTML + CSS + JS ;)

Comment: What did they use? Was it some form of C, C+, C++?